# How to make a UIButton in interface builder compatible with a 4 inch iPhone

Tags: uibutton, storyboard, ios6, segue, xcode4.5

I have just install Xcode 4.5 and trying to learn new features and tools.

I have set one background image from storyboard and checked whether `'Apply retina 4 factor'` and `'Apply retina 3.5 factor'` is working fine or not. its working ok.

I have put one `UIButton` but its not changing its position looks something like this

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me in this ?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

Just had to look in to `Auto Layouts` and `Constraints`.
[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2) was the helpful link for me.
Hope it helps someone else too!! :)